# how do we make the distinction between fibers and stalks in French?

Tags: mathematical-french

In English, if we speak of the stalk of a locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module (say), we mean its stalk as a sheaf. If we speak of the fiber, we mean the same thing after killing the maximal ideal.

I remember confusing these two things when I was learning about them, and how nice it was to have different words, so I was surprised when browsing through EGA to see the word "fibre" used in French to describe the stalk of an (arbitrary) sheaf. What do we say in French for the fiber of a locally free sheaf at a point?